# How to get attribute for shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have constructed a shortcode like this:

```
[myshortcode id="4"]content[/myshortcode]
```

with this:

```
<?php
function f_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    $returned_string = '<div class="wrap">';
    $returned_string .= '<div class="frame">'.$content.'</div>';
    $returned_string .= '</div>';
    return $returned_string;
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'f_shortcode');
?>
```

What i need from my shortcode is to retrieve a record from option table in the database (i.e retrieve content based on the id given in the shortcode)

In the options table i have this:

```
a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:2:"id";s:1:"4";s:9:"title";s:5:"test";s:11:"content";s:5:"test content";s:13:"shortcode";s:29:"[myshortcode id="4"][/myshortcode id="4"]";}}
```

So to retrieve the content i have added this peace of code to my function:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id' => 'id'
), $atts));

if(get_option('results_options') && get_option('results_options') != ''){
    $results = get_option('results_options');
    foreach ($results as $result){
        if($result->id == '{$id}'){
            $content = $result->content;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

In my table the content is there, but it doesnt display or it doesnt even be retrieved, Is there a problem with my code ?

How to get the `id="4"` parametre inside the function to retrieve the record from the database with it ?

Comment: First thing that i noticed is that in your options you have this recorded `s:29:"[myshortcode id="4"][/myshortcode id="4"]";` which i doubt will render your shortcode functionning. since the paramater is passed in the enclosing tag.

Comment: I construct it and stock it in the database for simple retrieve later, and you are right the encosing tag shouldnt contain parameters